# Override the block for custom product type

Tags: blocks, overrides, custom-product-type

I have created a new product type called "packet" and I wanna to override the block only if the product is packet on frontend. I have tried using below code in config.xml but its not working.

```
<catalog>
       <rewrite>
                 <product_view_type_packet>
                     Mymoduel_Test_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Packet
                  </product_view_type_packet> 
       </rewrite>
</catalog>
```

Please advise if you have solutions.

Comment: have added a new attribute set for product ? or else create product type like `simple, configurable, grouped, downloadable, etc.`

Comment: I have added both product type and attribute set as well.

Comment: The linebreaks are probably breaking the xml, try to use `<product_view_type_packet>Mymoduel_Test_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Packet</product_view_type_packet>` as one line